# How to translate top link

Tags: magento-1.7, xml

I Have top link as "Inspiration" in page.xml.How can I translate it in another language.

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                    <label>Inspiration</label>
                    <url>inspiration</url>
                    <title>Inspiration</title>
                    <prepare>true</prepare>
                    <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
                    <position>4</position>
 </action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you install your different language Pack. I give example of France Language.

1) In your theme folder/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv

2) Open this csv file and write as below formate

```
"Inspiration","Your France Translation"
```

3) Flush your cache and Just run your France Site it will Display This Translation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you translated Inspiration in your language files? If not, all you should have to do is to add

```
"Inspiration","tranlation to specific language"
```

at the bottom of app/locale/en_US/translate.csv. Then doing the same for any other language where the translation is needed.

Don’t forget to clear out your cache after making changes to the translation files, otherwise the changes won’t show up on your homepage.

Comment: I don't have any translate.csv file in en_us folder.

Comment: create file named translate.csv

Answer (score 0):

Inside /app/locale you should have `en_US` folder

1) You must install the language package you need your store to be translated in ( see http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations ) you can use the connect manager to install it.

2) Open your new language folder inside /app/locale/"newLanguage_NEWLANGUAGE"

3) Open Mage_Customer.csv with notepad and add a line:

"Inspiration","Your translated word"

4) Create a store view which will use your translated language (see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-store-view)